# How to avoid responsive tables in Buefy

Tags: css, vue.js, bulma, buefy

In a Buefy table I need to display the data as a regular *table* with columns horizontally on all media, not with the stacked cards on mobile. To fit the content I use a media query to simply hide all but the most important columns.

```
  <b-table :data="this.standings">
     <template slot-scope="props">
         <b-table-column field="pos" numeric>{{props.row.pos}}</b-table-column>
         <b-table-column field="name">{{props.row.name}}</b-table-column>
         <b-table-column field="details" :visible="useFullTable()">{{props.row.details}}</b-table-column>
            ...
```

Hiding the detailed column data works, but the table still switches to card view when the viewport is small.

Is there any way I can disable the responsive behavior? Note I only want to do this for this one table or view, I don't want to set the global breakpoints differently or disable reactive tables entirely in the app.

Comment: You meant responsive, not reactive.

Comment: Indeed. Fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://buefy.github.io/#/documentation/table) you can turn off mobile cards by binding the `mobile-cards` property of the table to `false`.

From my understanding you should be able to do the job using:

```
<b-table :data="this.standings" :mobile-cards="false">
// Table content
</b-table>
```

Comment: Thanks I was simply blind!